# Python error "IndentationError: expected an indented block"

Tags: python

This is my program and I am getting the following mentioned error:

```
def main():
    print "hello"

if __name__=='__main__':
main()
```

#### Error

```
  File "hello.py", line 8
    main()
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: `main()` should be indented inside if condition

Comment: i dont have ne idea about indented :

Comment: Hint: when you wrote `print "hello"`, does that have spaces at the start? **Why** does it have those spaces - what do they mean? Now, what if you try applying the same logic, to the part where the error occurred?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Normal Code
    Indent block
    Indent block
        Indent block 2
        Indent block 2
```

You should do:

```
def main():
    print "hello"

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

It can be either spaces or tabs.

Also, the indentation does NOT need to be same across the file, but only for each block.

For example, you can have a working file like this, but it is *not* recommended.

```
print "hello"
if True:
[TAB]print "a"
[TAB]i = 0
[TAB]if i == 0:
[TAB][SPACE][SPACE]print "b"
[TAB][SPACE][SPACE]j = i + 1
[TAB][SPACE][SPACE]if j == 1:
[TAB][SPACE][SPACE][TAB][TAB]print "c
```

Answer (score 6):

Your indentation is off. Try this:

```
def main():
    print "hello"

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

---

All function blocks, as well as *if-else*, looping blocks have to be indented by a tab or four spaces (depending on environment).

```
if condition:
    statements  // Look at the indentation here
    ...
Out-of-block // And here
```

Refer to *[2.1.8 Indentation](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.1/ref/indentation.html)* for some explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Your code should look like:

```
def main():
    print "hello"

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something like:

```
def main():
    print "hello"

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Pay attention to the indentations. Leading whitespace at the beginning of a line determines the indentation level of the line, which then is used to determine the grouping of statements in Python.

Comment: Does this require a better IDE to use for coding ..Since in vim or gedit we didnt focus to identations ?

Comment: It is not absolutely necessary but it would help a lot. Vim is quite powerful, you can turn it into a python IDE by some configuration. I personally use Aptana Studio most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

I am just sharing this stupidity. I had a very similar error, `IndentationError: expected an indented block def main()`, since I had commented out the whole body of a previous "some_function".

```
def some_function():
    # some_code
    # return

def main():
    print "hello"

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```