# Python code for image analysis and Bioinformatics

Tags: python, python-3.x

Facing problem to open fasta file in Pycharm IDE. I have installed Biopython package in Python 3.5 version

My code is:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
for seq_record in SeqIO.parse("z.txt", "fasta"):
print(seq_record.id)
print(repr(seq_record.seq))
print(len(seq_record))
```

After running the code, the output is:

> C:\Users\DHR\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\Scripts\python.exe
>   C:/Users/DHR/.PyCharmCE2018.3/config/scratches/scratch.py   File
>   "C:/Users/DHR/.PyCharmCE2018.3/config/scratches/scratch.py", line 3
>       print(seq_record.id)
>           ^ IndentationError: expected an indented block
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please add a plain python tag

Comment: A second duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14069096/2988730

Answer (score -1):

```
from Bio import SeqIO
for seq_record in SeqIO.parse("z.txt", "fasta"):
    print(seq_record.id)
    print(repr(seq_record.seq))
    print(len(seq_record))
```

Please indent the code.